# LINQ: Guid Compare Ignore case

Tags: linq, equals, guid, case-insensitive

I want to check if a variable of type guid exist. I used

```
new Db().JobCreate.Any(a => a.GuidVariable1.Equals(GuidVariable2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

but I get the error `Member 'object.Equals(object, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have another instance variable named `GuidVariable2`.
Unless there's something else involved I'd just do the following:

```
new Db().JobCreate.Any(a => a.GuidVariable1 == GuidVariable2);
```

If the variables are actually `string`s I'd do the following:

```
new Db().JobCreate.Any(a => a.GuidVariable1.ToLower() == GuidVariable2.ToLower());
```

Update based on comment:
`Guid` represents a hexidecimal number, so the case of the alpha digits is irrelevant. When represented as a `string`, case could be Upper, Lower or a combination but the actual number is the same:

```
var guid1 = Guid.Parse("a0449976-604e-4bdf-826d-234c4564c3e0");
var guid2 = Guid.Parse("A0449976-604E-4BDF-826D-234C4564C3E0");
var guid3 = Guid.Parse("A0449976-604E-4bdf-826d-234c4564c3e0");
guid1 == guid2; //true
guid2 == guid3; //true
```

Comment: I want to compare ignoring case

Comment: So the variables are actually of type `string` not `Guid`?

Comment: They are of type guid, but a guid can have lower or uppercase letters

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
new Db().JobCreate.Any(a => string.Equals(
    a.GuidVariable1, GuidVariable2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

(this is of course assuming your so-called GUIDs are actually strings, if you want to compare GUIDs just do this:)

```
new Db().JobCreate.Any(a => a.GuidVariable1.Equals(GuidVariable2));
```

Comment: tried that but did not work since I am using Guid not strings